# Trazer Registros Que Não Tem - 3° Tabela

Tags: mysql

Cenário, quatro tabelas.

```
TABELA A  |  TABELA B    |      TABELA C     |       TABELA_D

   ID_A     ID_B   ID_A        ID_B   ID_D           ID_D   DESC
    1        10      1          10      1             1     PEÇAS
                                10      1             2     SERVIÇOS
                                10      1             3     COMPRA
```

A primeira tabela tem a **PK ID_a**.

A segunda tabela tem a **PK ID_b** e **FK ID_A**.

A terceira tabela tem a **FK ID_B** e **ID_D**.

A quarta tabela tem a **PK ID_D**.

E tem esse `SELECT`:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CATEGORIES
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            `segmento`,
            `categoria`,
            dealer_rating_categories.id_categoria,
            IFNULL(
                round(
                    avg(
                        dealer_rating_categories.rating
                    )
                ),
                "NULL"
            ) AS media
        FROM
            DEALER_RATING_CATEGORIES
        JOIN DEALER_RATINGS ON DEALER_RATINGS.ID = DEALER_RATING_CATEGORIES.ID_AVALIACAO
        JOIN DEALERS ON DEALERS.ID = DEALER_RATINGS.ID_CONCESSIONARIA
        WHERE
            DEALERS.ID = 17
        AND DEALER_RATING_CATEGORIES.ID_CATEGORIA = CATEGORIES.ID
        GROUP BY
            dealer_rating_categories.id_categoria,
            segmento
    )
UNION
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        CATEGORIES
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT
                `segmento`,
                `categoria`,
                dealer_rating_categories.id_categoria,
                IFNULL(
                    round(
                        avg(
                            dealer_rating_categories.rating
                        )
                    ),
                    "NULL"
                ) AS media
            FROM
                DEALER_RATING_CATEGORIES
            JOIN DEALER_RATINGS ON DEALER_RATINGS.ID = DEALER_RATING_CATEGORIES.ID_AVALIACAO
            JOIN DEALERS ON DEALERS.ID = DEALER_RATINGS.ID_CONCESSIONARIA
            WHERE
                DEALERS.ID = 17
            AND DEALER_RATING_CATEGORIES.ID_CATEGORIA = CATEGORIES.ID
            GROUP BY
                dealer_rating_categories.id_categoria,
                segmento
        )
```

Estou precisando trazer na consulta os dados da **TABELA D** que não tem na **TABELA C**.

Exemplificando: o **ID 1** da **TABELA A** tem um registro estrangeiro na **TABELA B**. E o **ID** da **TABELA B** tem registros na **TABELA C**. E na **TABELA C** tem o **ID** da **TABELA D**.

Nesse exemplo acima, a **TABELA C** está preenchida apenas com informações com o **ID 1** da **TABELA D**.

Mas eu quero trazer na consulta registros que não estejam na **TABELA C**, que fazem parte da **TABELA D**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tive que criar uma quarta tabela porquê os resultados estão vindo com o valor da coluna repetida, obviamente.

Criei uma tabela chamada *CATEGORY_SEGMENTS* com o ID da Categoria. Como podem ver na imagem abaixo, o padrão continua... serão sempre 9 linhas. Mas a coluna Segmento tem que ser o valor que tem nessa tabela. Na tabela *DEALER_RATING_CATEGORIES* eu criei a coluna ID_CATEGORIA_SEGMENTO para poder ligar com essa tabela nova.

Fiz um LEFT JOIN na query que você montou, mas não deu certo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### ATUALIZAÇÃO

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    cs.segmento,
    c.categoria,
    cs.id,
    IFNULL(m.media, 0) AS media
FROM
    categories c
INNER JOIN dealer_rating_categories drc ON 1 = 1
RIGHT OUTER JOIN category_segments cs ON cs.id = drc.id_categoria_segmento
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        DEALER_RATING_CATEGORIES.id_categoria_segmento,
        DEALER_RATING_CATEGORIES.ID_CATEGORIA,
        IFNULL(
            ROUND(
                AVG(
                    DEALER_RATING_CATEGORIES.RATING
                )
            ),
            0
        ) AS MEDIA
    FROM
        DEALER_RATING_CATEGORIES
    INNER JOIN DEALER_RATINGS ON DEALER_RATINGS.ID = DEALER_RATING_CATEGORIES.ID_AVALIACAO
    INNER JOIN DEALERS ON DEALERS.ID = DEALER_RATINGS.ID_CONCESSIONARIA
    WHERE
        DEALER_RATINGS.ID_CONCESSIONARIA = 17
    GROUP BY
        id_categoria_segmento
) m ON m.id_categoria = c.id
AND m.id_categoria_segmento = drc.id_categoria_segmento
GROUP BY
    cs.id
ORDER BY
    c.id,
    drc.segmento
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agora sim, está retornando de acordo com o que deseja, mas se me permite uma sugestão, para esta query específica, poderíamos ter uma **tabela para segmento**, pois como pode ver na solução, tive que fazer o **JOIN** usando o campo **segmento que é um varchar**.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       drc.segmento, 
       c.categoria, 
       c.id,
       IFNULL(m.media, 0) AS media
  FROM categories c
 INNER JOIN dealer_rating_categories drc ON 1 = 1 
  LEFT JOIN ( SELECT
                    SEGMENTO,
                    DEALER_RATING_CATEGORIES.ID_CATEGORIA,
                    IFNULL(
                        ROUND(
                            AVG(
                                DEALER_RATING_CATEGORIES.RATING
                            )
                        ),
                        0
                    ) AS MEDIA
                FROM DEALER_RATING_CATEGORIES
               INNER JOIN DEALER_RATINGS ON DEALER_RATINGS.ID = DEALER_RATING_CATEGORIES.ID_AVALIACAO
               INNER JOIN DEALERS ON DEALERS.ID = DEALER_RATINGS.ID_CONCESSIONARIA
                WHERE
                    DEALER_RATINGS.ID_CONCESSIONARIA = 17
                GROUP BY
                    DEALER_RATING_CATEGORIES.ID_CATEGORIA,
                    SEGMENTO ) m ON m.id_categoria = c.id 
                                AND m.segmento = drc.segmento
 ORDER BY c.id, drc.segmento
```

> RESPOSTA ANTERIOR

Amigo, como já tinha postado pra você nos comentários, se fizermos o *UNION* sugerido, na prática, teremos todos os registros da **TABELA_D - categories**. Então "invertendo" sua SELECT, tomando por base a tabela principal sendo a TABELA_D, chegamos a uma solução melhor. A seguir:

```
SELECT `segmento`,
       `categoria`,
        dealer_rating_categories.id_categoria,
        IFNULL(
            round(
                avg(
                    dealer_rating_categories.rating
                )
            ),
            "NULL"
        ) AS media
  FROM categories TD
  LEFT JOIN dealer_rating_categories TC ON TC.id_categoria = TD.id
  LEFT JOIN dealer_ratings TB ON TB.id = TC.id_avaliacao
  LEFT JOIN dealers TA ON TA.id = TB.id_concessionaria 
 WHERE TA.id = 17
 GROUP BY TC.id_categoria, segmento
```

Espero que esta solução seja útil.

> RESPOSTA ANTERIOR

O uso da cláusula EXISTS não resolveria seu problema? Algo do tipo:

```
SELECT *
  FROM tabela_d
 WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT * 
                     FROM tabela_c 
                     JOIN tabela_b ON tabela_b.id_b = tabela_c.id_b
                     JOIN tabela_a ON tabela_a.id_a = tabela_b.id_a 
                    WHERE tabela_a.id_a = X
                      AND tabela_c.id_d = tabela_d.id_d );
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54208/discussion-on-answer-by-emerson-js-trazer-registros-que-nao-tem-3-tabela)